# Center text in EditText not working programmatically when adding background resource

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am working on an app that inserts an EditText box programmatically onto the layout. I cannot seem to get the center text working when I add the EditText programmatically but it works fine when I do it through the XML layout. I have nailed down the problem to be when I add the background resource. I have added code below to show both EditText when added through code and also XML.

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/layoutLinear_main"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@drawable/background" >             

   <LinearLayout 
      android:id="@+id/layoutLinear_answerDisplay"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"       
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <EditText 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:paddingLeft="5dp"
         android:paddingRight="5dp"
         android:paddingTop="5dp"
         android:paddingBottom="5dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:background="@drawable/background_field"            
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
         android:textSize="30dp"
         android:hint="F"
         android:text="F" />

  </LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

Then within the main code. I add an EditText programmatically. I've removed the margins and paddings, just to clearly identify the issue.

```
LinearLayout layoutLinear_answerDisplay = ((LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.layoutLinear_answerDisplay));

EditText ed = new EditText(this);               
ed.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;        
ed.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

ed.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_field);
ed.setTextSize(30);
ed.setHint("F");
ed.setText("F");

layoutLinear_answerDisplay.addView(ed);
```

The following is then the ouptut. You can see from the image that the top EditText has centered text (this was done through the XML code). You can see from the bottom EditText, that the text is off centered (done through the code behind).

[image]

I have also attached my background resource for the EditText. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the layout_margin (Left & Right) to center the xml edittext. when you set those in code you're not taking into account the dp scaling.

```
    final int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            (float) 120.0, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

use something like the above to scale your 120 measure to the correct pixel equivalent and then they will be in the same place.  But realize also that you shouldn't need to use such high values for the left/right margins to get your text centered

Comment: Hi @dangVarmit, after reading your comment, I decided to remove the dependancy on the margins and padding to see would this work. On testing the code, I have nailed down the problem to be when adding the bacground resource (i.e. ed.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_field)). Would you know of any reason why this would be effecting the centering of the text? I'll update my main question to represent my findings

Comment: A nine patch with padding defined could change the centering. Padding is defined with black lines on the bottom and right pixel edge

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the problem. It was due to the blacklines. I had them on the right hand side of the nine patch image, so i just put them across both sides and it work perfectly. Thank you very much for your help